# sizeWithFont: in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am getting a warning: "'sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0"
Can anyone please suggest me an alternative for this method?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Calculate height based on cell content — cell content will stretch appropriately when the height is set
Post *post = self.articleComments[indexPath.row];
CGFloat width = tableView.frame.size.width - 71 - 15;  // Width of comment text area
UIFont *commentFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SeroCompPro-Light" size:14];
CGFloat commentTextHeight = [post.text sizeWithFont:commentFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 10000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;

return commentTextHeight + 31 + 37;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7)

Comment: Yes but that is for CGRect , i need for CGFloat .

Comment: again that is for CGRect i need for CGfloat ,CGFloat commentTextHeight = [post.text sizeWithFont:commentFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 10000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;

Comment: this is line where i am getting the warning ,and my output is not displaying properly .

Comment: But from CGSize u can get height.Check labelSize.height.I have used it for setting height

Comment: What do you mean "that is for CGRect"??  There is no CGRect in that function at all.

Comment: yeah CGSize , hey can you write the answer then , as i am new to ios.

Comment: SO isn't about always getting 100% code written for you it is about getting answers

Comment: From the labelsize, use CGFloat commentTextHeight = labelSize.height;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is deprecated  in ios 7.
Instead of this function

sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode

use this function, Use

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context

 boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:
```

Calculates and returns the bounding rect for the receiver drawn using the given options and display characteristics, within the specified rectangle in the current graphics context.

Parameters
size
The size of the rectangle to draw in.

options
String drawing options.

attributes
A dictionary of text attributes to be applied to the string. These are the same attributes that can be applied to an `NSAttributedString` object, but in the case of `NSString` objects, the attributes apply to the entire string, rather than ranges within the string.
context

The string drawing context to use for the receiver, specifying minimum scale factor and tracking adjustments.

Comment: This function is available from iOS 7, so be careful about the backward compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative is:

```
- (NSSize)sizeWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
```

In your case:

```
[string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontwithName:@"SeroCompPro-Light" size:14]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used bellow code and it works:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: font
     }];

    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];

    result = CGSizeMake(ceilf(rect.size.width), ceilf(rect.size.height));
```

Problem at creating a NSAttributedString and get properly width height with ceilf method

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution for  supporting IOS7 and lower version-

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeWithAttributes:)])
{
    expectedLabelSize = [subTitle sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:subTitleLabel.font}];
}else{
    expectedLabelSize = [subTitle sizeWithFont:subTitleLabel.font constrainedToSize:subTitleLabel.frame.size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
}
```