# sizeWithFont: replacements

Tags: ios, nsstring, ios7, nsattributedstring

The following NSString methods have been deprecated in iOS 7:

```
    - (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use -sizeWithAttributes:");

    - (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:
(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:");

    - (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:");

    - (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:");
```

While the replacement for the first one is straightforward, the rest not so much. What are  the equivalent calls to `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` to obtain exactly the same result?

In particular:

- What should be the value of `options`?
- How do you specify the `lineBreakMode`?

Comment: I have a feeling that this issue is about to fuel SO for the next year

Comment: It should be noted that this question contains most of the answer to mine (even if the scope was different): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7?rq=1. Maybe a more detailed answer to the other question would be more appropriate. I'm voting to close my own question just in case.

Answer (score 1):

.How do you specify the lineBreakMode?

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
[attributedStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                 value:paragraphStyle
                 range:NSMakeRange(0,[attributedStr length])];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
CGRect new = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, 300) options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil];
CGSize stringSize= new.size;
```