# IOS 7 sizeWithFont Deprecated

Tags: ios7, deprecated, sizewithfont

I cannot seem to replace the deprecated `sizeWithFont` with `boundingRecWithSize` correctly. I scoured through all the answers and stayed up all night trying to fix this.I really need help from someone way smarter than I. Here is the code I am trying to modify. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CGSize sizeForText = [faqItem.answer sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]
   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tblView.bounds.size.width - padding, MAXFLOAT)
   lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

[sectionInfo insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundf(sizeForText.height + 5)]
  inRowHeightsAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aminFontSize%3aactualFontSize%3aforWidth%3alineBreakMode%3a):

> sizeWithFont: Returns the size of the string if it were to be rendered
>   with the specified font on a single line. **(Deprecated in iOS 7.0. Use
>   sizeWithAttributes: instead.)**
>
> - (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font Parameters font The font to use for computing the string size. Return Value The width and height of
>     the resulting string’s bounding box. These values may be rounded up to
>     the nearest whole number.

So you can use  [sizeWithAttributes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes%3a) like this:

```
 CGSize sizeForText = [faqItem.answer sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]}
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tblView.bounds.size.width - padding, MAXFLOAT) 
                           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

[sectionInfo insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundf(sizeForText.height + 5)] 
      inRowHeightsAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the sizeWithAttributes property.

```
CGSize mysize = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]}];
```

You can also set it to an already created font size in order to reduce recoding if you use the size more than once:

```
CGSize mysize = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: label1.font}];
```

I do not believe you can use constrainedToSize with this property.  It would have to be separately set on a CGRect.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an sample for you, hope it's helpful.

```
NSString *text = @"    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.";
CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
NSDictionary *attrDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]};

rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(100,9999)
                          options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                       attributes:attrDict
                          context:Nil];

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lbl.text = text;
rect.origin = CGPointMake(50, 200);
lbl.frame = rect;
lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```