# Update deprecated code

Tags: ios, xcode

Can you please help with adopting code to iOS 7? 
I have code:

```
size = [string sizeWithFont:font
                   forWidth:constrainedToSize.width
              lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];
```

But Xcode says that sizeWithFont:font  sizeWithFont:font  and lineBreakMode deprecated in iOS 7.

Help me please with update this line of code.

Comment: Always use the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:), it clearly says what the replacement method is.

Comment: Have a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sizeWithAttributes:` which takes an NSDictionary.

```
CGSize fontSize = [string sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]}];
```

Comment: Now its say: unused variable "fontSize"

Comment: is your problem solved? just try this NSLog(@"size of string is %@",NSStringFromCGSize(fontSize)); it will remove the warning

Comment: please vote and tick if it's the correct answer