# Get text height depending on width

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, width, uitextview

I have a NSString with any number of characters.
Now wand to draw this String into a rect.
The rect needs to be for example 250 pixels wide.

I wand to know how to get the height of this text
with a specific font and size.

Comment: Please see the methods in the `UIStringDrawing` category of `NSString`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the NSString UIKit Additions ([https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aconstrainedToSize):)

use 
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:

Use it in a way that you use constraints with a width of 250 in your case and some very high amount in height (let's say 10000).
Then it returns the actual width (which may be slightly smaller than 250) and the height needed.

But be aware that it was deprecated recently. You can use 
boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:
From iOS 7 onwards. Usually a deprecated method is around for a while but you cannot rely on that. So if you want your app to run in iOS 6 or even older then you would probably go with the deprecated method for a while or you could check the OS and either use the old or the new method for going forward.

Apologies if you are on OS-X and not iOS. In that case my answer would not be helpful at all. You did not tag the OS.

Comment: He tagged with UITextView which is certainly iOS

Comment: `sizeWithFont` is deprecated in iOS 7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7

Comment: @swilliams, correct, it is deprecated which was considered within the answer already.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the height and width using the 'sizeWithFont:' method as shown below:

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];

// Get the width of a string ...
CGSize size = [@"Some string here!" sizeWithFont:myFont];
```

CGSize is a C structure, so you can access the height and width as follows:

```
  // Print height and width
  NSLog(@"h: %f \t w:%f", size.height, size.width);
```

Comment: `sizeWithFont` is deprecated in iOS 7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7