# sizeWithFont deprecated use boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

Tags: objective-c

I know there are lots of answers to similar questions but I have tried and tried but can't any of the replacements to work. The problem line is below where I am getting the error `sizeWithFont` is deprecated use `boundingRectWithSize: options: attributes: context:`

```
    CGSize contentSize = [myString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(650, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

I have also seen that `sizeWithAttributes` should be used. And I have also seen that some replacement code is a number of lines long which hardly seems a step forward.

Can anyone help me with the correct replacement line?

Update:

I have tried

```
CGSize contentSize = [myString sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]}];
```

but that still leaves the

```
constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(650, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Is this no longer needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7) - if none of the answers there are appropriate for you, please explain why in greater detail.

Comment: Yes but not a complete answer - there is no replacement for constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(650, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

Comment: You can using http://stackoverflow.com/a/18951386/1445366