# SizeWithFont deprecated in IOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7

How to change

```
CGSize size=[tempStr sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 56)];
```

to make it work with IOS7

Comment: See   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`sizeWithAttributes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:), using something like:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f];
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
CGSize size = [tempStrig sizeWithAttributes:attrDictionary];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    CGFloat finalHeight;

    CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(requiredWidth,9999);

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:yourRequiredFont, NSFontAttributeName,nil];

    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourText attributes:attributesDictionary];

    CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

    if (requiredHeight.size.width > requiredWidth) {
        requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0,requiredWidth, requiredHeight.size.height);
    }

    finalHeight=requiredHeight.size.height;
```