# Lost with the replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have a warning that sizeWithFont: is deprecated, i have try to replace it to sizeWithAttributes: but everything i try is not working.

The code is supposed to tell me the expected size of a UILabel and the cCell is the cell and the label fro the IB.

Thanks for all your help.

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(210, FLT_MAX);

expectedLabelSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:cCell.lblHotelResponse.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:cCell.lblHotelResponse.lineBreakMode];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sizeWithAttributes:` instead.

```
NSDictionary *attributeDict = @{NSFontAttributeName:cCell.lblHotelResponse.font};
CGSize expectedLabelSize    = [labelText sizeWithAttributes:attributeDict];
```

Another way is:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelText attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: cCell.lblHotelResponse.font}];
CGRect rect                          = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
CGSize labelSize                     = rect.size;
```

References:

1. [sizeWithAttributes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac///documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:)
2. [boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac///documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:)