# UILabel automatic height as per the length ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, height, uilabel

I have a UICollectionView as shown below.The **titleLabel** as you can see should vary its height as per the content.the background view **labelView** also should change its height.How can i do that?

[image: collectionview label]

i used...

```
-(CGFloat) heightForText:(NSString *)text withWidth:(CGFloat) textWidth{

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(textWidth, 20000.0f);
    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                       options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.titleLabel.font}
                       context:nil];
    CGFloat height = rect.size.height;

    height = ceilf(height);
//    NSLog(@"height %f", height);
    return height;
}
```

i used this like ...

```
CGRect newFrame = cell.titleLabel.frame;
      newFrame.size.height = height;
       cell.titleLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

I am getting the new frame to the label.but the height increases from a fixed y towards down.Here now i have to lift the y according to the height.Is there any other way?

Comment: This thread might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ankit's code to get the Height required for the label and use autoLayout as shown below.

Add a **view --->** **set leading,trailing and bottom constraints** to it with respect to the cell superView.

Then **add the label as subView to this view.ADD all the four constraints.ie,set leading,trailing,top and bottom constraints**

now, use the above Ankit's code (I have pasted below) to get the height of the label and set it to the label frame.

```
-(CGFloat) heightForText:(NSString *)text withWidth:(CGFloat) textWidth{

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(textWidth, 20000.0f);
    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                       options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.titleLabel.font}
                       context:nil];
    CGFloat height = rect.size.height;

    height = ceilf(height);
//    NSLog(@"height %f", height);
    return height;
}
```

set the new frame to the label now.

```
CGRect newFrame = cell.titleLabel.frame;
      newFrame.size.height = height;
       cell.titleLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Hope it works.**It is all about properly setting autolayout**.Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Here goes the method

```
-(CGFloat) heightForText:(NSString *)text withWidth:(CGFloat) textWidth{

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(textWidth, 20000.0f);
    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                       options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.titleLabel.font}
                       context:nil];
    CGFloat height = rect.size.height;

    height = ceilf(height);
//    NSLog(@"height %f", height);
    return height;
}
```

Comment: `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]`  should be replaced with  `cell.titleLabel.font`

Comment: I am getting the height.But the height of label in cell is not changing.Why is it so?

Comment: I am getting the new frame to the label.but the height increases from a fixed y towards down.Here now i have to lift the y according to the height.Is there any other way?Getting the height is not my requirement.I have to align the label as in the image.HOw to do this?please help.