# Adding UILabel programmatically only by code. Sizing ? (Swift)

Tags: swift, size, uilabel, font-size

I try to add a UILabel by code which works, but not as intended.

With following Code I can see the label but the height of the label is not correct as you can see in the attached screen. I would like the uilabel sized so the height of the label corresponde to the fontsize.

Of course I could simply oversize the UILabels high so the text would fit. But I don't think thats best practice.

How do I size an UILabel based on a fontsize ?

```
var uilabel1=UILabel();
uilabel1.frame=CGRectMake(0, drawy, screenwidth, ititlesize);
uilabel1.text=sTextViewOptionsTitle;
uilabel1.font = UIFont(name: uilabel1.font.fontName, size: 28);
self.view.addSubview(uilabel1);
var lastelementheigth=uilabel1.frame.height;
```

[image]

**UPDATE Solution with sizeToFit()**

Thanks for the answer regarding sizeToFit(). This did the trick with some additional code to position the control.
updated Code:

```
  var uilabel2=UILabel();
    //uilabel2.frame=CGRectMake(0, drawy, screenwidth/2, DropdownHeigth);
    uilabel2.text=sTextSizeTextViewer;
    uilabel2.font = UIFont(name: uilabel2.font.fontName, size: iFontsize_Option);
    uilabel2.sizeToFit();
    uilabel2.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: drawy);

    self.view.addSubview(uilabel2);
    lastelementheigth=uilabel2.frame.height;
```

Comment: Have you tried `sizeToFit`?

Comment: Thanks a lot that did the trick ! I updated my question with updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may only need to call [`-sizeToFit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit). This will change the label's size to its "preferred" size based on its contents. Then you can reposition the origin or center if desired.

Comment: But howto change the origins without setting the frame ?

Comment: In Swift, you can say `label.frame.origin = CGPoint(...)`. Or you can use `label.center = CGPoint(...)`

Comment: Thanks thats even much better. I will update the code for others.

Answer (score 0):

It's been asked before - take a look at:
[Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7)

The method you're looking for is `sizeWithAttributes`