# How to have dynamic font size for all devices without using size classes in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to add the dynamic font size for my labels,textfields in iOS for all the devices.I know i can tackle this by using size classes but i don't want to use size classes.How can i make a custom class & generate the dynamic font size for all iOS devices (iPhone4,4,6,6+,iPad).I have a clue of using `layoutsubView` method.Please tell me how can i achieve this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth may be it will help you

Comment: Other than that how can i support.Please tell.Maybe creating a custom class for diffrent screen sizes.

Comment: Have a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7