# fontWithSize(fontSize: CGFloat) is available from which ios Version

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I was using this function to change the font size of a label in UIButton.
Like this(SWIFT) :-

```
Button!.titleLabel?.font = Button!.titleLabel?.font.fontWithSize(12)
```

I want to see the availability of this funtion for ios 7. So i see the quick help documentation of Xcode. There it was mentioned as `iOS (8.0 and later)`

[image: Xcode Help Text]

Then i went on to search for the appropiate funtion on apple website but there it is wriiten that its available from `Available in iOS 2.0 and later.` See [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIFont/fontWithSize:) for ref.

Please do let me know which one to trust.

I saw answer but i am not that satisfied as i check the other class 
Like `NSMutableAttributedString` for swift

here it is written as available from `iOS (3.2 and later)`
[image: NSMutableAttributedString Availability]

Comment: have u seen it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7

Comment: It is available earlier, if I had to guess I'd say since Swift came with iOS8 the Swift documentation doesn't know that method before that.

Comment: @PKT I think what you have given me is for **sizeWithFont:** but my question if for **fontWithSize**.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It means i can use it for both IOS 7 and IOS 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My strong guess is that since Swift came out together with iOS 8 Apple's documentation won't show anything being available before that. If you check the same method on Objective-C side, you'll see the same as on the web:

[image]

I also have a project targeting iOS 7 with calls to `fontWithSize` in Objective C and they work fine. So there should be no reason for it to not be available on Swift side of things.

Also found information from [Apple's Radar system](http://www.openradar.me/23630349):

> Engineering has the following feedback for you:
>
> This is expected - Swift was not available until WWDC 2014 and the introduction of iOS 8, therefore the availability of these methods and contstants in Swift is correctly documented as iOS 8+.
>
> Thank you for your feedback. Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended.

So clearly this is the Apple way of doing things, as usual.

Comment: Thanks Sami... That is a possible explanation.

Comment: But i think i am not satisfied with this also

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta Found response from Apple saying this is actually exactly the reason, edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks .. but then why NSMutableAttributedString is shown as 3.2 and later ?

Answer (score 0):

in Objective C

it is still 2.0

[image]