# How to fix 'sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:' is deprecated: warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecation-warning

My code is

```
CGSize textSize =  [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width - 106, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Anyone knows how can i fix this warning?

Comment: may be this works `NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        CGRect textRect = [strText boundingRectWithSize:size
                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle.copy}
                                             context:nil];`

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7

Comment: I am not familiar with objective-c, i have this warning in a library that i use in swift project. Trying to fix

Comment: If you not familiar with ObjectiveC code. Use https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code. It will convert ObjC to swift

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Swift

```
 // adjust the label height (top align text)
// old
var labelSize: CGSize = model.name.sizeWithFont(self.nameLabel.font,  constrainedToSize: maxNameLabelSize, lineBreakMode: self.nameLabel.lineBreakMode)
// new
var labelSize: CGSize = model.name.boundingRectWithSize(maxNameLabelSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self.nameLabel.font], context: nil).size
```

> Objective c

```
 // adjust the label height (top align text)
 // old
CGSize labelSize = [model.name sizeWithFont:self.nameLabel.font
                      constrainedToSize:_maxNameLabelSize
                          lineBreakMode:self.nameLabel.lineBreakMode];
 // new
CGSize labelSize = [model.name boundingRectWithSize:_maxNameLabelSize
                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.nameLabel.font}
                                        context:nil].size;
```

Comment: Nothing to do with linebreakmode.Use lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping as it is

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
 NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is long text..!!!" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.lbl.font
 }];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){self.lbl.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];

NSLog(@"Height %f",rect.size.height);
NSLog(@"Width %f",rect.size.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width - 106, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[[UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUR_FONT_NAME" size:12.0f]]}
                                 context:nil];

CGSize size = textRect.size;
```