# UITableview Dynamic Cell height

Tags: objective-c, tableview

How to increase the UITableView custom cell height based on the webview content in objective c?

```
Flower * flower = [self.filteredflowers objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
NSString * text = flower.descriptionText;
CGSize constraints = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 7), 20000.0 f);
CGSize size = [text SizeWithFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: FoONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize: constraints lineBrakeMode: UILineBreakModeWordwrap];
```

I wrote this code, but it's showing the `sizewithfont` and `UILineBreakModeWordwrap` method is deprecated in present xcode. I need replacement of this methods. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a minimal code sample or image to illustrate the problem. Show us what you tried so far and what you expect from a working sample.

Comment: Flower *flower = [self.filteredflowers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *text = flower.descriptionText;

CGSize constraints = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 7), 20000.0f);

CGSize size = [text SizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FoONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize: constraints lineBrakeMode:UILineBreakModeWordwrap];

I wrote this code, but its showing the "sizewithfont" and "UILineBreakModeWordwrap" method is deprecated in present xcode.

I need replacement of this methods.

Thank you.

Comment: A WebView content could not be stable, not even in time. So practically if you mean the height of WevView based on its content, then I don't think this makes sense. Apart from that I am sure you know that you can get the height of the WebView component, but probably this is not what you want.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7