# Detect tap for UILabel with Autoshrink to minimum font size enabled

Tags: uilabel, multiline, swift5, autoshrink

I am using the following UITapGestureRecognizer that I modified so others could copy and paste to see the same output as me.

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)

        //let mutableAttribString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        //mutableAttribString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: label.font!], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: label.attributedText!.length))

        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        //let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: mutableAttribString)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines

        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        print("LabelSize=",labelSize)

        textContainer.size = labelSize
        print("TextContainerSize=",textContainer.size)

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        print("LocationOfTouchInLabel=",locationOfTouchInLabel)

        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        print("TextBoundingBox=",textBoundingBox)
        //let textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                              //(labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
        print("textContainerOffset",textContainerOffset)

        //let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
                                                        // locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)
        print("LocationOfTouchInTextContainer",locationOfTouchInTextContainer)

        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        print("IndexOfCharacter=",indexOfCharacter)

        print("TargetRange=",targetRange)
        return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
    }

}
```

I set the label like so to detect clicks like other answers have said to do:

```
formulaLabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(tapLabel(gesture:))))
```

It is set to attributed.

In case it matters I have the following code that performs an animation with the text.

```
func doFormulaAnimation(){
        //animTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true, block: {_ in
            //Draw correct formula based on mode.

        var formula = ""
        var highlight_ranges:[NSRange] = []

        if(stateController?.tdfvariables.ebrtMode == true){
            formulaLabel.numberOfLines = 1
            formula = "BED = N * d * [ RBE + ( d / (α/β) ) ]"

            self.formulaLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formula, attributes: [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.label ])

            if(self.dosePerFractionSelected==true){
                highlight_ranges.append(NSRange(location: 10, length: 1))
                highlight_ranges.append(NSRange(location: 24, length: 1))
            }

            if(self.alphaBetaSelected==true){
                highlight_ranges.append(NSRange(location: 29, length: 3))
            }

            if(self.totalDoseSelected==true){
                highlight_ranges.append(NSRange(location: 6, length: 5))
            }

            if(self.numFractionsSelected==true){
                highlight_ranges.append(NSRange(location: 6, length: 1))
            }
        }

        if(stateController?.tdfvariables.ldrMode == true){
            formulaLabel.numberOfLines = 3
            formula = "BED = R * T * [RBE + (( g * R * T) / (α/β) ) ]\ng = ( 2 / μT ) * ( 1 - ( ( 1 - exp(-μT) / μT ) )\nμ = 0.693 / Thalf repair"
        }

        if(stateController?.tdfvariables.permMode == true){
            formulaLabel.numberOfLines = 2
            formula = "BED = ( R0 / L ) * [ RBE + ( R0 / ( ( u + L) * (α/β) ) ) ]\n"
        }

        UIView.transition(with: self.formulaLabel, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                let colorAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.label ]
                let attributedTextFormula = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formula, attributes: colorAttribute)

                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 6
                paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
                //paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

                attributedTextFormula.addAttribute(
                    .paragraphStyle,
                    value: paragraphStyle,
                    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedTextFormula.length
                ))


                self.formulaLabel.attributedText = attributedTextFormula
                //
            }, completion: { finished in
                print("finished first transition")

                UIView.transition(with: self.formulaLabel, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    let colorAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.label ]
                    let attributedTextFormula = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formula, attributes: colorAttribute)
                    for range in highlight_ranges {
                        attributedTextFormula.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
                    }

                    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 6
                    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
                    //paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

                    attributedTextFormula.addAttribute(
                        .paragraphStyle,
                        value: paragraphStyle,
                        range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedTextFormula.length
                    ))

                    self.formulaLabel.attributedText = attributedTextFormula
                    //self.formulaLabel.addInterlineSpacing(spacingValue: 1)
                }, completion: { finished in
                    print("finished second transition")
                })

        })
    }
```

The code above demonstrates me creating the NSMutableString accordingly and setting the paragraph style and line spacing accordingly (I have a hunch this may be the issue but not sure how to test that) etc...

Finally I have my tap label function

```
 @IBAction func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let text = formulaLabel.attributedText?.string else {
            return
        }

        let AB_Range = text.range(of: "(α/β)")

        //let AB_Range = NSRange(location: 29, length: 3)
        if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: formulaLabel, inRange: NSRange(AB_Range!, in: text)) {
           print("Tapped a/b")
        } else {
           print("Tapped none")
        }
    }
```

**Currently it does not tap on the correct location but is off by a very large degree**.  Upon debugging it becomes obvious why it's not working but I am not sure how to fix the code or where it went wrong.

When i click on the A/B like I'm supposed to I get this as the debug info.

```
LabelSize= (315.0, 43.0)
TextContainerSize= (315.0, 43.0)
LocationOfTouchInLabel= (266.0, 28.0)
TextBoundingBox= (0.0, 0.0, 185.373046875, 13.8)
textContainerOffset (64.8134765625, 14.6)
LocationOfTouchInTextContainer (201.1865234375, 13.4)
IndexOfCharacter= 36
TargetRange= {28, 5}
Tapped none
```

The part where it calculates the textbounding box or textcontaineroffset or the locationoftouchintextcontainer are **most likely the error points** but I'm not sure which it is since this is hard to understand.

I can tell it's not working correctly because in my string it's no where near the end and it always says indexofcharacter=36 no matter where I click past it, which means it's not calculating something correctly with one of the variables I mentioned above.

Any help is appreciated if they know why this isn't working.

To give an idea how the text looks right now I'll show you below.  My end goal is to make it so I can click on parts in the formula to get values to appear, so clickable links you could say.

[image]

UPDATE::

I forgot to mention that when I updated the UITapGestureRecognizer and add these lines:

```
let mutableAttribString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        mutableAttribString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: label.font!], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: label.attributedText!.length))
```

and set it to the text storage, `let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: mutableAttribString)` I do seem to see some improvements in the numbers but it's still way off.

```
LabelSize= (315.0, 43.0)
TextContainerSize= (315.0, 43.0)
LocationOfTouchInLabel= (269.0, 25.5)
TextBoundingBox= (7.505859375, 0.0, 299.98828125, 42.9609375)
textContainerOffset (0.0, 0.01953125)
LocationOfTouchInTextContainer (269.0, 25.48046875)
IndexOfCharacter= 17
TargetRange= {28, 5}
Tapped none
```

You will notice the textboundingbox more closely resembles the labelsize at least.  I read somewhere that an issue could be if you are using different fonts so this is why I tried adding that in to be sure it's working correctly.

Also interestingly, adding this to the UITapGestureRecognizer seems to help also:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 6
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        //paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

    mutableAttribString.addAttribute(
        .paragraphStyle,
        value: paragraphStyle,
        range: NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableAttribString.length
    ))
```

I noticed the textbounding box shows 0,0 correctly when I do this instead of 7.50

```
LabelSize= (315.0, 43.0)
TextContainerSize= (315.0, 43.0)
LocationOfTouchInLabel= (262.5, 31.0)
TextBoundingBox= (0.0, 0.0, 299.98828125, 42.9609375)
textContainerOffset (7.505859375, 0.01953125)
LocationOfTouchInTextContainer (254.994140625, 30.98046875)
IndexOfCharacter= 17
TargetRange= {28, 5}
Tapped none
```

**MAJOR UPDATE*****

Well great news! It turns out that the **font fix** was part of the fix, but because I had **autoshrink enabled with a minimum font size** and maximum font size it was never calculating correctly! **When I set to a fixed font size everything works!**

Question is now **how to make it work with autoshrink enabled?** Note that you will have to set size to something very large to prove this works, like I set mine to 55 so it autoshrinks accordingly and then you see the error, if the default size is smaller then it seems to work fine, which tells me the error has something to do with the size being initially very large maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out an acceptable answer.

The key is the code below:

```
let formulaLabelWidth = formulaLabel.bounds.size.width

var font_size:CGFloat = 36.0 //Change this to a higher number if you need to.
var stringSize = NSString(string: formula).size(withAttributes: [.font : self.formulaLabel.font.withSize(font_size)])
while(stringSize.width>formulaLabelWidth){
    font_size = font_size - 1
    stringSize = NSString(string: formula).size(withAttributes: [.font : self.formulaLabel.font.withSize(font_size)])
}


 formulaLabel.font = formulaLabel.font.withSize(font_size)
```

What this code does is draws the string as if it had a certain font size giving you the boundaries in width and height.  In my case I only care about the width thanks to a trick with how you set up the UILabel in interface builder.

[image]

For this strategy to work this MUST be set on your UILabel since it does all the hard work of finding the perfect size in which the text will fit.

This **DOES work with Multiple Lines** as well as I am using that for many of my formulas.  The lines are separated with \n characters and is automatically accounted for since it just adds to the height of how it would draw with the `.size(withAttributes)` function.

They used to have a sizeForFont but it was deprecated so I looked into that function as a possible solution and indeed it does work with some clever thinking.

As for detecting a tap use the following modified UITapGestureRecognizer that I created.

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)

        let mutableAttribString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        mutableAttribString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: label.font!], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: label.attributedText!.length))

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 6
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
        mutableAttribString.addAttributes([.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle], range: NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttribString.string.count))

        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: mutableAttribString)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        let labelSize = label.bounds.size

        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)

        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        //let textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                              //(labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)

        //let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
                                                        // locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)

        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        print("IndexOfCharacter=",indexOfCharacter)

        print("TargetRange=",targetRange)
        return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
    }

}
```

Feel free to remove the comments, but I left them there so you could see that it is selecting the correct index of the strings.

Also note that I had a paragraph setting in there with line spacing of 6 and alignment center so feel free to change those to your use case but do not change the line break mode! That is critical to the system automatically finding the optimal font size when it draws.

Also in this code is reference to the current labels font, this was the new part I added, because without it the text-storage calculations would be way off as pointed out in other answers on stack-overflow.

Put it together with the function for the tap gesture

```
@IBAction func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let text = formulaLabel.attributedText?.string else {
            return
        }

        let AB_Range = text.range(of: "(α/β)")

        //let AB_Range = NSRange(location: 29, length: 3)
        if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: formulaLabel, inRange: NSRange(AB_Range!, in: text)) {
           print("Tapped a/b")
        } else {
           print("Tapped none")
        }
    }
```

and of course set the tap gesture to the UILabel in viewDidLoad or where appropriate...

```
formulaLabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(tapLabel(gesture:))))
```

And you have yourself a working

- Multiline Friendly
- Autoshrink Friendly
- Clickable Friendly

UILabel!